# Execute more than two lines of bash code in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I am trying to write  python code which will execute following steps in cmd terminal in linux machine

```
cd /path/to/destination/
3dAFNItoNIFTI *epi*
```

i tried calling `subprocess.call` two times, once to cd and then impleemnt that command. but it doesnt seem to work.

Is there a way to call two line inux command code using subprocess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`cd`ing in one `subprocess` call will not affect another, since they are executed in different processes. You want to use [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir):

```
with os.chdir("/path/to/destination"):
    subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Not all versions of Python support `with os.chdir`; if yours doesn't, you can do this:

```
old_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("/path/to/destination")
subprocess.call(cmd)
os.chdir(old_dir)
```

Comment: getting an error... `import os
>>> import subprocess
>>> with os.chdir("/Users/sdb99/E1000"):
...     subprocess.call("3dAFNItoNIFTI /Users/sdb99/E1000/*3d_scan_2*orig")
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__` @mipadi

Comment: @tryeverylanguage: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @tryeverylanguage: I updated my answer to avoid using `with`, which I think is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import commands
my_work = "cd /path/to/destination/ ; 3dAFNItoNIFTI *epi*"
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(my_work)
```

**getstatusoutput** returns the return status (of the last bash command) and the returned output (from *stdout*)

Comment: Apparently this didnt help. the command didnt execute.. didnt get any error too but output file is not seen

Comment: I submitted an edit to the code to correct a mistake : `my_work` have to be passed in argument to `getstatusoutput`. Anyway this should only work on python 2.* as I guess there is no more `commands` module in python 3.

Comment: `command` is working fine in linux terminal but when called uisng subprocess it gives error `/bin/sh: cd/Users/sdb99/E1000 | 3dAFNItoNIFTI *3d_scan_2*orig*: No such file or directory
127`  any idea what might have caused this? @Prune

Answer (score 0):

got the way to do it:

```
import subprocess

command = command = """cd /path/to/destination | ls -al | pwd"""
b = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: Correct idea, but wrong implementation. Replace the first `|` with either `&` or `;` depending on whether you want a failure in the `cd` command to stop the whole pipeline or not, respectively. Piping the output of `cd` to `ls` *happens* to work here, but more or less by accident.